# Is the linearity assumption of OLS harmed?

Tags: multiple-regression, residuals

Below is the residual plot of my multiple linear regression analysis. The model has heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation present but I am unsure if the linearity assumptions is also harmed. The model roughly follows the horizontal zero residual line. Is this sufficient to assume linearity in this case?

If not, how could I potentially solve the problem?

[image]

[EDIT: see comment section]

Here are the summary plots of fitting a beta model by dividing the dependent variable/100.

[image]

I wonder which model is fitting better...

Comment: From the plot is appears that you dependent variable is bounded so a linear regression model is probably not appropriate. Please provide more details about your study, the data and your research question(s).

Comment: Yes, my dependent variable is bounded between 0.01 and 100 but continuous in between. It's an index measuring the level of CSR disclosure of companies. My indep. variables are mostly numerical, continuous variables such as profitability, total assets etc. I also have two dummy variables (1=0) measuring media exposure and if the company operates in high-polluting sector. I try to measure relationships between those firm and industry variables and the level of CSR disclosure (index). I have seen multiple studies using linear regression and using the same index as the dependent variable.

Comment: Seeing other studies do something wrong is not a reason to do something wrong yourself. The model is clearly not a good fit for the data. You probably need some kind of GLM. You might consider posting the data itself along with details of how the data were collected and your study design, to get good answers.

Comment: Totally agree but also see the context. I am a BA student only having been exposed to linear regression analysis so far. Having seen many scientific papers being published in major journals using the same methodical approach makes me confident that my approach must be "good enough" for where I am right now. I cannot upload data as it is proprietary (Bloomberg). However, I accounted for heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation with HAC standard errors. But, I am unsure if the linearity assumption is also violated? Any other idea from the top of your head how I could potentially improve the fit?

Comment: This is a bit like asking a mechanic what is wrong with your car without letting them see inside it ;) You said the DV is  "measuring the level of CSR disclosure of companies". So to start with please explain exactly how CSR index is measured (I know what CSR is, having just googled it). My first step would be to divide the DV by 100 and fit a beta model.

Comment: haha this is a funny analogy!:D Ok, so the index is being calculated based on three pillars: environmental, social and governance categories each equally weighed. Bloomberg reviews websites/reports etc. to measure the extent of CSR information for each company within a specific year. Ratings are adjusted for industry. The score ranges from 0.01-100. However, the exact calculation a weighing process is not publicly communicated as this is Bloomberg's secret sauce. Companies that disclose no CSR information at all are rated with an NA.

Comment: I'm glad you see the funny side of it :) Do you have data for which industry and country the companies are based in ? Some kind of multilevel / mixed effects model may be warranted, though I don't think that alone would solve the problem (have you tried fitting a beta model?)

Comment: I do have data for industry but I restricted the analysis to S&P 500 companies so it's only US companies in the dataset. I also tried to fit the beta model and the out looks promising from the first look. However, I have no idea how to validate the model and interpret the results. Maybe you can help me out. I included a picture of the plots in my initial post above.

Comment: Can you please add this new information as an edit to the post. Not everybody reads comments!